# Harder proof using tools from Category Theory rather than Set Theory

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, alternative-proof, multilinear-algebra

For this question I'm assuming a person who knows both basic set theory and category theory (functors, natural transformations, limits, colimits, adjacents).

There are theorem proofs that get "easier" (not rigorouly I mean something like shorter, easier to read, needing less tools) when you use category theory tools rather than set theory ones, some examples may be found in multilinear algebra.

I'd like a "the other way" theorem: easy proof using set theory, complicated proof using category theory.  I want theorem with at least two known proofs, at least one using category theory tools and at least one using set theory ones.

Thank you very much for any idea!

Comment: The book *Mathematics Made Difficult*, by Carl E. Linderholm, seems relevant here.

Comment: What do you mean by "category theoretic" and what do you mean by "set theoretic"? People tend to use the easiest tool for the job. For instance, there's a "category theoretic" proof that $\frac{5}{2} = 2 + \frac{1}{2}$. After all, they are both the [groupoid cardinality](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/04/13/counting-objects-up-to-isomorphism-groupoid-cardinality/) of the action shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130626062746/http://imageshack.us/a/img132/228/actionj.png). Of course, this is more complicated than the traditional "set theoretic" proof ($\frac{5}{2} = \frac{4+1}{2}$)

Comment: In a more serious vein, there are proofs of the independence of the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) which go through set theoretic [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)), and there are also proofs which go through some sheaf or topos theoretic argument (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5854.pdf)). Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the differences to actually turn this into a proper answer, or even say which is "more complicated". Both proofs require a fair bit of machinery.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Re: CH, my understanding of the category-theoretic approach is that it essentially recapitulates the set-theoretic argument in categorical language, and so becomes a bit harder. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Arguably to someone more comfortable with the language of topos theory, it's actually Cohen's proof that is harder. If you're looking for an independence proof, why do we care that the generic extension is also transitive or added no new ordinals?

Comment: I guess category-theoretic arguments become more complicated in case one uses a lot of implicit identifications that would require explicit identifications to make the arrow chasing go smooth. Sometimes, $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is nicer to work with than $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.